# how to get lat and long on touch event from google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

Is it possible to get latitude and longitude from Google map on touch event?

For example: if i touch the New York on map, it should give me the latitude and longitude of New York.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get the location from most of the touch events, e.g.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        int X = (int)event.getX();          
        int Y = (int)event.getY();

        GeoPoint geoPoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(X, Y);
    }
```

Answer (score 18):

Instead of intercepting the TouchEvent with an overlay you can set an `OnMapClickListener` directly on the GoogleMap object.

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener(){
        void onMapClick(LatLng point){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                point.latitude + ", " + point.longitude,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

How to get the GoogleMap Object from a `MapFragment` or a `MapView` see
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#add_map_code