# Select an Area in MapView Android

Tags: android, android-mapview, selection, area

Is is possible to show a map-view in android an allow the user to select an area for example a country or state ?

Clarification :

I want to let users select a country from the map view , How is that possible ?

I don't care about whether the selected country is highlighted or not , I only care about retrieving which country was selected / touched/ marked by the user

Comment: select means you want to mark particular area or individual area?

Comment: ya allow the user to mark it and get that information so that I can do something useful with it

Comment: well, there's no method that a country should be highlighted, you have to write the code yourself to draw border line for each country, than this will be peice of cake :p

Comment: @AdeelPervaiz : If you read my question again , "I don't care about whether the selected country is highlighted or not"  I only care about retrieving which country was selected / touched/ marked by the user

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a method to get lat, lon from map
[how to get lat and long on touch event from google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646584/how-to-get-lat-and-long-on-touch-event-from-goole-map)

After that you can call Google Geo Code API to convert this lat,lon to physical address,

i.e.

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false
```

The Above link will return JSON

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": street_address,
    "formatted_address": "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "275-291",
      "short_name": "275-291",
      "types": street_number
    }, {
      "long_name": "Bedford Ave",
      "short_name": "Bedford Ave",
      "types": route
    }, {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "New York",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Brooklyn",
      "short_name": "Brooklyn",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Kings",
      "short_name": "Kings",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "NY",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "11211",
      "short_name": "11211",
      "types": postal_code
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 40.7142298,
        "lng": -73.9614669
      },
      "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 40.7110822,
          "lng": -73.9646145
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 40.7173774,
          "lng": -73.9583193
        }
      }
    }
  },

  ... Additional results[] ...
```

Now you can parse JSON and get country name city name locality, state etc etc.

Or other option is to get just country code.

```
http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=25.03&lng=67.2
```

this will return country code PK = Pakistan
you can either get the country code list, or

Answer (score 1):

One solution I know is that you can mark particular area by map pins and fill that area with some color by extending OverLay class in Map like below. Hope this is useful.

```
public class MapOverlay extends Overlay
{
    private GeoPoint new_geopoint = null;

    public MapOverlay(GeoPoint geoPoint) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setAlpha(9);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Path path = new Path();

        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

        for(int j = 0; j < geoArrayist.size(); j++) 
        {
            Iterator<GeoPoint> it = geoArrayist.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) 
            {
                GeoPoint arrayListGeoPoint = it.next();

                Point currentScreenPoint = new Point();
                projection.toPixels(arrayListGeoPoint, currentScreenPoint);

                if(j == 0)
                    path.moveTo(currentScreenPoint.x, currentScreenPoint.y); 
                else
                    path.lineTo(currentScreenPoint.x, currentScreenPoint.y);
            }                 
        }
       // old_geopoint = new_geopoint;
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but please check the clarification