# MapFragment Inflated Activate Through EditText

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, mapfragment

Im having a problem in inflating the map. At first if I click the `EditText` It will launch, If I cancel / ok the `AlertDialog.Builder` , and click again the `EditText` it will cause:

`E/MapError: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment`

The logic is: **I'm done with the Region and Province**. Passing the Region and Province in the `MapFragment` to set Camera Position of the selected Region & Province, this is my only problem aside from the MapError.

[image: sample] :

My code for `Map`:

```
//START MAP FRAGMENT DIALOG
public void alertOrgMapSetMarker(){

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View getView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.map_inflate_org,null);
                   mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment_org);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertMap = new AlertDialog.Builder(AdminCreateEventActivity.this,R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
    alertMap.setTitle("Mark Location")
            .setView(getView)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

    AlertDialog mapDialog = alertMap.create();
    mapDialog.show();
}
```

I cannot `getView` from this line of code. In order to have control. I want to `@Override -`[setMapClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646584/how-to-get-lat-and-long-on-touch-event-from-google-map)

`mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment_org);`

My inflated XML: map_inflate.xml

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment_org"
    map:cameraBearing="112.5"
    map:cameraTargetLat="10.3157"
    map:cameraTargetLng="123.8854"
    map:cameraTilt="45"
    map:cameraZoom="30"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:uiCompass="true"
    map:uiRotateGestures="true"
    map:uiScrollGestures="true"
    map:uiTiltGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
```

I really need your help. Thank you.

Comment: Is `AdminCreateEventActivity`  extends `FragmentActivity` or `simple Activity` ?

Comment: @M D: You are thinking of a `SupportMapFragment` problem?

Comment: It `extends` AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @RoCk try to extends `FragmentActivity` or use `SupportMapFragment`

Comment: I will try your suggested answer. I will just inform if it works. :)

Comment: cannot `extend` multiple class It already extends `AppCompatActivity`, Can you post an suggested answer with steps. I remove the `MapFragment` and Replace with `MapView` it gone. :(

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` extends `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` so you have to use `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a `MapView` for a Map inside a Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment_org" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think so. You can use any `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment` inside `Fragment`

Comment: If I change my `MapFragment` I can now use `getView` from my View?

Comment: My map's gone :( I will post a screen shot for my error